# Arduino wifi shield server - can't access "get" http response using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arduino, server

I have an arduino wifi shield which is running the standard code that is provided in the tutorial (http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiWebServer). Then I go on chrome and access the ip address that arduino server is running on. Here is prints out the data that is required, so I see the page being updated and everything.

Now I want to access that data from my computer through an html page. I used the following to "GET" the data from that address however this is giving me problems. I am unable to get this to work. I can't get the status to ever be 200. I always get a 0.

```
    <div id="myDiv"></div>

    <script>
    alert(window.location.host);
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //alert(xmlhttp.readyState);
    alert(xmlhttp.status);
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://192.168.0.101/", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    </script>
```

My computer and the shield are both on the same network as I am connecting to them through the same router. I can't seem to have any luck trying to configure this correctly.